# How to change partition size on Ubuntu and Windows dual boot system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I asked a friend to install Ubuntu 14 and Windows 8 installed on my laptop. The partitioning was done as follows:

NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT            LABEL
sda           931.5G
├─sda1 ntfs     300M                       Recovery

├─sda2 vfat     100M /boot/efi
├─sda3          128M
├─sda4 ntfs   126.4G
├─sda5 ntfs   341.8G /mnt/C6E4BB0FE4BB00AB

├─sda6 ntfs   443.2G
├─sda7 swap     1.9G [SWAP]
└─sda8 ext4    17.6G /

Ubuntu is installed on sda8, with size 17.6 GB. I need more space on my ubuntu as I now carry out most of my work there.

Is there a way to alter the size of the partitions, or should I reinstall?

Comment: ask the friend who installed it for you

Comment: You may instead consider connecting one of your ntfs partitions to Ubuntu to store and access data and documents. Thus, you can access all data from both operating systems. For this to work well, you need to always shut Windows fully down (no hibernate) with fast start disabled so the Windows partitions are properly closed before you start Ubuntu. This way, you would not need to repartition.